# Is it possible to access and read localstorage for an electron application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, electron

I have built an electron app that allows the user to move elements such as divs around the screen, and saves their locations in localstorage as a class. This is so when the page reloads or is reopened after a session, the changes made persist. I can't get electron to access the local storage though, even on a page change, so I was wondering if there is anyway to make electron go and grab the localstorage classes, or if I can make the page itself do it.

Comment: what you mean by "localhost access"?

Comment: that would be me meaning to say localstorage, and being distrait and putting the wrong thing. It is meant to be local storage

Comment: Have you checked the docs? https://electronjs.org/docs/faq#how-to-share-data-between-web-pages

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the docs, I will take a look at them

Answer (score 29):

You can read data from localstorage. Here is what work for me.

```js
mainWindow.webContents
  .executeJavaScript('localStorage.getItem("thekey");', true)
  .then(result => {
    console.log(result);
  });
```

Answer (score 10):

You gets the entire localStorage and use it as you would do it in a browser.
The localStorage variable now is an object with key-values.

```js
mainWindow.webContents
  .executeJavaScript('({...localStorage});', true)
  .then(localStorage => {
    console.log(localStorage);
  });
```

Comment: Please consider explaining how and why this solves the problem.